# How can I make my papers available on Sci-Hub?

Tags: online-publication, open-access, sci-hub

An essential assumption of this question is that **I own**, without restriction, the copyright of my papers.  I am a novice Sci-Hub user.  How do I make my papers available to other Sci-Hub users?

Edit:  If your answer is to post the paper somewhere other than Sci-Hub, please explain how that leads to the paper being available in Sci-Hub.  I want to target people who only look at Sci-Hub for papers.

Answer (score 11):

"Sci-Hub is a shadow library website that provides free access to millions of research papers and books, without regard to copyright, by bypassing publishers' paywalls," source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub). "Sci-Hub obtains paywalled articles using leaked credentials."  So, it seems, Sci-Hub focuses on papers owned by corporations, rather than individuals.

There's surely less interest in providing access to papers owned by individuals, since those individuals can simply make their papers publicly available. Nonetheless, let us suppose that Sci-Hub takes an interest in making more works available. Then you just need to make papers available where Sci-Hub looks.

Even technical report repositories such as arxiv may forbid Sci-Hub from redistributing papers. So, there isn't much of an incentive for Sci-Hub to move into this space: They create trouble for little reward.

Sci-Hub could start looking at personal websites, but, what's the reward? The material is already accessible. Sci-Hub could also start allowing authors to upload content, but, again, what's the reward?

I don't really see why Sci-Hub would invest in making papers owned by individuals more accessible.  Their niche is elsewhere.

Comment: The reward would be that the papers are online in the same repository (and possibly with the best version).

Comment: "Then you just need to make papers available where Sci-Hub looks."  Where is that?

Comment: @user111388 At what cost?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Publishers' websites. As explained, I don't see any motivation for Sci-Hub looking elsewhere, e.g., arxiv or personal websites.

Comment: @user2768: I am not talking about if this is feasable or not (I don't know). All I am saying is that I see an advantage in having it available on SciHub (also because the website could go down at any time). You are asking what the reward is and I answered

Comment: @user111388 Let me rephrase: I see no reward for SciHub, since the cost is too high. Of course, I'm speculating, I don't run SciHub. I don't question the benefit to users.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

SH/LG allow users to upload books & papers, although the upload interface can be tricky to find. The paper upload interface is at (currently): http://librarian.libgen.gs/scimag/librarian/

Comment: Welcome to aca.se, gwern! This is the closest thing that exists to a positive answer, but it's not quite precise: The interface you've linked uploads papers to the (somewhat unrenowned) magazine section of LG, **not** to SH. From what I understand, the former contains the latter, but not vice versa. For example, [here](http://libgen.gs/scimag/index.php?s=10.1016%2F0021-8693%2871%2990112-8-alt&journalid=&v=&i=&p=&redirect=1) is an unofficial scan uploaded manually to LG via your interface. It is [not](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(71)90112-8-alt) on SH.

Comment: That seems unlikely. The 'magazine' section is MagzDB, which is not even under the libgen.* domain names, and you can clearly see in your own link that it is labeled 'Scientific Articles' and further includes a link to 'Sci-Hub' so LG sure thinks that the paper got into SH... I can't say why the SH proxy-domain+DOI query combo doesn't work, other than that there is a *lot* of brokenness around SH in 2021 specifically, on top of all of the usual UX/UI bugs it's always had.

Comment: The "sci-hub.se/(optionally https://doi.org/)DOI" query works for all articles that SH has saved, so I'm afraid it has not saved ones uploaded to LG, even if they were uploaded before 2021.

Comment: I can confirm that uploading to LibGen's Scimag *was* the correct solution when that was still possible. But shortly after SciHub announced that it is no longer accepting new articles, the upload page for Scimag stopped working.

Even today you can see that any article available via Scihub is also on Scimag, and vice versa as long as the DOI is entered correctly in LibGen's metadata. With the current embargo SciHub is effectively functioning as a simplified interface to download from LibGen's Scimag.

Answer (score 7):

First, congratulations for defending free access to knowledge.

As for the question itself, as @Lighthouse Keeper said, the question should be reformulated. Since what the SCI-HUB proposes is to making accessible the scientific texts closed by paywall. So, at the first glance your text isn't targeted for this tool. However you could upload your work to the initiative libgen (a cousin to SCI-HUB).

However, something that were not said yet is you can publish in Open Access Journals. There are some journals that are really good - just be alert to the predatory ones.

**

In addition, I have seen some researchers that leave their publications linked on their professional pages. Here are trade-offs to do. Get a DOI and recommends the use of sci-hub or publish on your own website (GitHub etc) without DOI.

But in any way, encouraging their colleagues, students and others to use the sci-hub and defending the free access to knowledge you already have an immense contribution.

Comment: "you can publish in Open Access Journals"  I tested this and Sci-Hub does include papers from at least one open access journal.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Weeding out Open Access Journals surely isn't worth the effort

Comment: Most Open Access Journals in my field charge a lot for publishing. That's not really an alternative with our limited resources where we can't even buy computers to write our papers on!

Answer (score 5):

Sci-Hub is not like arXiv, bioRxiv, ChemRxiv, viXra, GitHub, FigShare, Mendeley, ResearchGate and Academia.edu, where you upload your own papers.

People do not upload their own papers to Sci-Hub. They publish papers in journals and Sci-Hub then makes the PDF copy of such journal papers, available for free.

If what you want to do is make your own paper available for free, I would suggest to use one of the platforms mentioned in the first sentence of this answer (except for SciHub).

Answer (score 3):

[Sci-Hub obtains paywalled articles using leaked credentials](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5832410/). So if you want to get your papers onto Sci-Hub, just follow this procedure:

1. Publish them in journals that your institution subscribes to.
2. Donate your institution credentials to Sci-Hub. If you can't do this legally, "accidentally" fall for one of the phishing emails Sci-Hub regularly sends.

They will do the rest.

Comment: Your #2 is unethical. Sorry, this is bad advice. You don't have authority to "donate" the credentials. Doing it "accidentally" is, of course, dishonest.

Comment: @Buffy tell that to einpoklum (check out their comments on my other Sci-Hub related answers). It's a topic I am sick and tired of. One might be able to tell how sick I am of the topic from this answer too, actually, since it suggests doing something illegal to help something that's also illegal.

Comment: It's as simple as step #1 *if* the journal is well covered by Sci-Hub. Most are, but some are not. If this is the case you can upload to LibGen and that will make it available on Sci-Hub within a few days. Donating your personal credentials is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I don't think I have ever received a phishing e-mail that I could associate with them. How do I recognize them from the other normal ones?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think the point of a phishing email is that you cannot identify the sender. So "accidentally" fall for every phishing email you see that's after your institutional password, and eventually one of the attackers will sell your credentials to Sci-Hub.

Comment: I too have never seen a phising email from sci-hub and the legal cases don't suggest that it has been part of their strategy.